# Display and scroll over big layout

Tags: android, android-layout

would be very grateful if anyone can advice how to solve the problem.

I got to draw a large and rather complicated structure (railway track layout). In order to have a smooth scrolling I wanted to draw the layout into a bitmap and then just to copy necessary part into the screen canvas in onDraw method.

The problem is that the layout is much larger than 2048x2048 (max allowed texture size on my Asus Prime) and I'm getting 'Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture'.
And this's even without zoom.

The layout is just a set of 2d geometrical primitives so maybe it's possible to work on geometrical rather than bitmap level, but how to implement smooth scroll and zoom then ?

What are common ways of solving this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tiled approach. Divide your large map within small ones and render them while you move. Like google maps does.

You could use the TMX format: http://www.mapeditor.org/

AndEngine http://www.andengine.org/ has an implementation for it.

Comment: Thanks !
Not sure about tiles though.
The elements of the layout are shapes of different size, shape and complexity. They can intersect, be a text etc - just pretty much anything.
It's also would be hard to divide the layout into small ones because some elements would be split apart. This might not be a problem for static bitmaps, but not that easy for geometrical figures that will be updated dynamically (only colors and shapes though, boundaries will stay the same) Google solves this problem, I think, by drawing geometrical figures (like roads or live traffic etc) on top of the image tiles.

Comment: yes google places stuff over the tiles, couldn't you pre-compile your layout and save it split info the required sections? And add add-ons over the split background?

Comment: Thanks mate, I've solved the problem (at least for now) by rendering my geometrical primitives into bitmaps. Apparently it's much faster to just draw a bitmap rather than drawing a shape.